# no enclosing instance of type Calculation

Tags: instance

```
package myPackage;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calculation {
    int z;

    public void addition(int x, int y) {
        z=x+y;
        System.out.println("sum of given input: "+z);


    }

    public void subtraction(int x, int y) {
        z=x+y;
        System.out.println("diff btwn given input: " +z);
    }

}


...............
package myPackage;

public class MyCalculation extends Calc {

        public void multiplication(int x, int y) {
            //z=x*y;
            System.out.println("product of given input: "+ x*y);

        }

    }

..............
package myPackage;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=20; int b=10;
        MyCalculation demo = new MyCalculation();
        demo.addition(a, b);
        demo.subtraction(a, b);
        demo.multiplication(a, b);

    }

}
```

This was my code, it's showing an error saying :

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type No enclosing instance of type
>   Calculation is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an
>   enclosing instance of type Calculation (e.g. x.new A() where x is an
>   instance of Calculation).

Any solution ?

Comment: Please format your question.